# error while copying the files in python(adding r prefix to the path)

Tags: python

I'm trying to copy few files from src to dest. getting src path from Jenkins.

```
sourceCodePath = from Jenkins(ex : "\\hydprespaas01\c$\New folder")
sourceCodePath = r+(to sourceCodePath)#to skip space(b/w New and folder) and consider it as path
dest = "destination path"
shutil.copy(sourceCodePath, dest)
```

I know that r prefix is only for string literals. Is there any way to ignore the space between New and folder so as to consider the path.

Comment: have you tried escaping the space?

Comment: Yes its working